# C/C++ ncurses freeze

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

Im currently experimenting with a small ncurses application.

What it *should* do is recieve a message via serial, that message is delimited with : and then it should show the different values in separate windows.
Ive used strtok to "split" it.

Ive got everything working, except the window text update, it updates one window correctly, and as soon as i update the next window it freezes.
Now, ive tried many different things with this, and had to revert back to a very crude way just to simplyfy it. Please see this code:

```
while(1){


read (fd, in,20);


s = strtok(in,":");




while (s != NULL)
{

    mvwprintw(winrpm,1,1,s);
    s = strtok(NULL, ":");
    mvwprintw(wintrans,1,1,s);
}

refresh();
wrefresh(winrpm);
wrefresh(wintrans);


//refresh();
}
```

everyting works as expected if i remove the second mvwprintw, but with that one in, it freezes after the first update.

Any ideas? I know im supposed to include all of my code, but its 98% ncurses window drawings and colors and stuff..

Comment: It's an endless loop. There is no waiting or anything. That's why it hangs.

Comment: Yes i know its an endless loop. Its very crude, but why does it only hang with one more window to update?

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I just added a if NULL break, and now it works. Need to figure out a better loop for it then. Didnt expect ncurses to freeze incase of null though, but it was careless of me. Thank you very much

Comment: user3121023 Do you want to add an answer, so that i can upvote you? It doesnt seem to work with just a comment! Thanks again.

Comment: Why is this tagged as both C and C++? Which language are you using?

Comment: Keith Thompson, I meant to use C++ since that is the language im trying to learn, however, several guides and posts told me that you use C calls for the serial comms, due to this i tagged both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. If the first strtok is not NULL, the token is printed to `winrpm` and the while will try to get another token and if successful will print the token to `winrpm` and `wintrans`.

```
while(1){

    read (fd, in,20);

    if ( ( s = strtok ( in, ":")) != NULL) {
        mvwprintw ( winrpm, 1, 1, s);
        while ( ( s = strtok ( NULL, ":")) != NULL) {
        {
            mvwprintw ( winrpm, 1, 1, s);
            mvwprintw ( wintrans, 1, 1, s);
        }
    }
    refresh();
    wrefresh(winrpm);
    wrefresh(wintrans);
}
```